# React useEffect function deps keep looping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this code

```
// snackbar.js
import { isString } from 'lodash';
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

const useSnackBar = () => {
  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([]);

  const closeSnackbar = useCallback(() => {
    toast.remove();
  }, []);

  const toastLoading = useCallback(message => {
    const key = toast.loading(message, { duration: 0 });

    setKeys(current => [...current, key]);
  }, []);

  const toastSuccess = useCallback(message => {
    toast.success(message);
  }, []);

  const toastInfo = useCallback(message => {
    toast(message);
  }, []);

  const toastError = useCallback(error => {
    if (error.response) {
      toast.error(error.response.data.message);
    } else if (isString(error)) {
      toast.error(error);
    } else {
      toast.error(
        'Something unexpected happened, we are investigating this issue right now',
      );
    }
  }, []);

  const displaySnackbar = useCallback((variant, data, options = {}) => {
    const closeLoading = () => {
      if (keys.length >= 1) {
        keys.map(() => closeSnackbar());
      }
    };
    closeSnackbar();

    switch (variant) {
      case 'error':
        toastError(data);
        break;
      case 'success':
        toastSuccess(data);
        break;
      case 'loading':
        toastLoading(data);
        break;
      case 'info':
        toastInfo(data);
        break;
      default:
        closeLoading();
    }
  }, []);

  return [displaySnackbar, closeSnackbar];
};


export default useSnackBar;
```

and use it like this

```
// import and upper code

const [displaySnackbar, closeSnackbar] = useSnackbar();

useEffect(() => {
  if (loading.data) {
    displaySnackbar('loading', 'Searching batch disbursement data');
  }
}, [loading.data, displaySnackbar]);

// return components
```

if I remove `displaySnackbar` deps from useEffect it works perfectly, but because it need to be deps (linter error) it keep looping when it got triggered.

Any solution?

Update:

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-resonance-m8h2vi

Comment: try removing `displaySnackbar` from dependency array and add `eslint-disable-next-line` above the dependency array

Comment: @DharmikPatel definitely it will solved if use eslint disabled, but i want to know which part of my code is wrong that trigger the loops.

Comment: Have you shared a [complete and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I've copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-useeffect-function-deps-keep-looping-gzg4b4) and can't reproduce any render looping issue.

Comment: @DrewReese added codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/red-resonance-m8h2vi as you can see on the log it will do the infinite loop

Comment: Well, if I fix your codesandbox to memoize the `displaySnackbar` function like you did in your snippet here it doesn't render loop.

Comment: Do you have a version of your `useSnackBar` hook that actually triggers a toast without the odd useEffect hook enqueueing state updates?

Comment: @DrewReese the real code it's fetching through the api. and its just a simple check if isLoading or not. hence i make the sandbox like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `keys` infinitely, I just added a condition to show you where the loop is

```js
  const toastLoading = useCallback((message) => {
    const key = toast.loading(message, { duration: 0 });
    if (message !== "Loading") {
      setKeys((current) => [...current, key]);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: doesn't fix the issue. it keeps looping in the background.

Comment: Are you seeing "Maximum update depth exceeded" when you update your code like I showed in the example? Also, you don't have `break` in default switch case

Comment: but I think I got an idea from your above snippets how to handle it. thanks! will mark this as correct.

Comment: sure, no problem. happy coding